# On AWS ECS with Fargate, why do I see 4GB of RAM inside the container even tough it was provisioned with just 512MB?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I have a service on ECS that is provisioned using Fargate. On the task definition, I have set `"memory": "512",`. Also, if I browse the task on AWS Console, I find `CPU | Memory: .25 vCPU | .5 GB`.

I'm able to log in the container. From there, if I run `free -m`, I get:

```
# free -m
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           3851         670         737           0        2444        2902
Swap:             0           0           0
```

If I use AWS Console and go to ECS -> Clusters -> Service -> Health and metrics, I see that 85% memory utilization. Which also doesn't make much sense.

Why am I seeing ~4GB of RAM, even tough I have declared 512MB? Why does ECS shows 85% memory utilization on monitoring, even tough its using more than 512MB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The user is jailed (via `cgroups`) to only use the amount of resources they have been sized. In that case it is 0.25 vCPUs and 512MB of memory. Fargate under the hood allocate a larger node but customers pay only for the task resources that are rounded up.
In other words, you only pay for the size of the task you requested, not for the size of the host we provisioned to back it.